# How to define a sass map for specific CSS selector

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins, scss-functions

I am trying to customize scss in my project so that I can use css variables according to css selector applied on outermost element.
The basic Idea I have is to define color variables and then use those color variables to define semantic color variables in two different css selectors.

```
$primary: orange;
$primary-dark: redorange;
$warn: red;
$accent: grey;
$dark-grey: #757678;
$light-grey: #f7f7f7;

$error-text: $warn;
.light {
    
    $background: $light-grey;
    $button-bg: $primary;
}

.dark {
    
    $background: $dark-grey;
    $button-bg: $primary-dark;
}
```

This is one solution I tried, but in scss we cannot change scope of variables according to selectors.

So I tried using functions.

```
$white: #fff;
$light-grey: #eaeaea
$primry-dark: redorange;
$primary: orange;
$black: #000;

  $semantic-colors: (
    background: (
      screen: $white,
      tile: $light-grey,
    ),
    buttons: (
      primary: $primary
      link: $white
      icons: $primary-dark;
    )
  );


  @function semantic-color($semantic-color:'background', $tone: "base") {
  // @return red;
  @return map-get(map-get($semantic-colors, $semantic-color), $tone);
}


.side-nav-link {
  background-color: semantic-color(background, tile);
}
```

The above code works fine. but I want to have a color map based on a theme. for eg:
dark has its own semantic color map and light has its own and I can access based on scope.

```
.light {
    $semantic-colors: (
    background: (
      base: $white,
      tile: $light-grey,
    ),
    buttons: (
      primary: $primary,
      link: $white,
      icons: $primary-dark;
    )
  );

}

.dark {
    
      $semantic-colors: (
    background: (
      base: $black,
      tile: $dark-grey,
    ),
    buttons: (
      primary: $primary-dark,
      link: $black,
      icons: $primary;
    )
  );

}
```

I can create two different maps within semantic-color map:

```
$semantic-colors: (
 light:(
    background: (
      base: $white,
      tile: $light-grey,
    ),
    buttons: (
      primary: $primary
      link: $white
      icons: $primary-dark;
    )
  ),
  dark:(
      background: (
      base: $black,
      tile: $dark-grey,
    ),
    buttons: (
      primary: $primary-dark,
      link: $black,
      icons: $primary;
    )
   )
 );
```

and then modify my function to get color within a specific map based on $theme variable.

For eg:

```
$theme: dark;

   @function semantic-color($semantic-color:'background', $tone: "base") {
  // @return red;
  @return map-get(map-get(map-get($semantic-colors, $theme), $semantic-color), $tone);
}
```

but I don't know a way to define $theme according to .light and .dark selectors.

If I try doing something like this:

```
.light {
    $theme: light;
}

.dark {
    $theme: dark;
}
```

and then use the $theme variable in the semantic-color function then I get the error $theme is not defined.

so my question is

**"Is there a way I can define $theme or semantic-color function or $sematic-color map according to a CSS selector (.light or .dark in my case)?"**

I have read sass documentation but could not find any solution to suit my situation.

Articles I referred to:

[Theming in SASS](https://medium.com/@sroskelley/theming-in-sass-67b8c0265e3f)

[Creating a Color Language in Web Interfaces (with Sass Maps)](https://medium.com/thinking-design/creating-a-color-language-in-web-interfaces-with-sass-maps-42898ecc6d79)

[educba SASS Map](https://www.educba.com/sass-map/)

Comment: @Alwasalearner: Thx for feedback to my answer. So I didn't get the question/idea indeed not the right way. Maybe you like to more focus/clarify your question.

Comment: Hi @Brebber, I am trying to change scope of scss variables like we do in css variables so that I can use light or dark theme. Here is an article which has suggested a way but I am not able to wrap my head around this solution https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1

Answer (score 0):

I am not quits sure if I did it completly right ... but as I see your idea and code in general works well.

The only thing seems to be: there had been some errors in your code seeting up `$semantic-colors` !?

This (correctedt version = only corrections in `$semantic-colors`) works here:

```
//########### SASS: demo file


//### VARS
$primary: orange;
$primary-dark: redorange;
$warn: red;
$accent: grey;
$dark-grey: #757678;
$light-grey: #f7f7f7;
$white: #ffffff;
$black: #000000;

$error-text: $warn;

$semantic-colors: (
  light: (
    background: (
      base: $white,
      tile: $light-grey,
    ),
    buttons: (
      primary: $primary, 
      link: $white,
      icons: $primary-dark,
    ),
  ),
  dark: (
    background: (
      base: $black,
      tile: $dark-grey,
    ),
    buttons: (
      primary: $primary-dark,
      link: $black,
      icons: $primary,
    ),
  ),
);


//### METHODS

$theme: dark;   

@function semantic-color($semantic-color: "background", $tone: "base") {
  // @return red;
  @return map-get(
    map-get(map-get($semantic-colors, $theme), $semantic-color),
    $tone
  );
}


//### STYLES

.light {
    $theme: light;

    background: semantic-color('background', 'base');
}



//###########################
//###### CSS: compiled file

.light {
  background: #ffffff;  // if $theme changes to dark this becomes #000000
}
```

Comment: Brebber, thanks for suggesting a solution.
But with this solution I have to wrap my scss selectors within .light selector which is not in my control.

Comment: Thx for feedback. I commented direct to your question. Here just a question to my understanding: why do you not have controll about the setting off the var. I am slightly confused ... are you not writing sass complete? Var is to write CSS. CSS class (maybe `body class=light`) is set after writing SASS/CSS in HTML/PHP, can do anywhere and has nothing to do with SASS var ...??? What is your whanted css output based on that var?

Answer (score 0):

Because of your comment I believe to understand your question better now. So, according to your last comment I add an additional answer as it is more an explanation about the general howto than a concrete answer to your code.

### **First: I believe your code (SASS-map/-function) works the right way**

To me it seems more a question about understanding how the theme technique works.

So let's start from the base:

#### 1. What you need to do for theming in `html`:

```
// set a theme anchor with classes
// --> class to body
<body class="theme_light">


   ... code ...
   ... all elements within body will be styled by theme-light-classes


   // or ALTERNATIVE do it with a marker where your app starts in html
   // --> class to app-root-element
   <div class="app_root theme_light">

      ... code ...
      ... all elements within app-div will by styled by theme-light-classes

   </div>

</body>
```

#### 2. Based on HTML what you nee in `CSS`:

Write the styling for your elements for both(!) themes based on the used marker technique (body or app) ...

```
// write styling classes for both themes (dark + light)
// as child selector based on the html theme-anchor-classes

/* stylings light theme */

.theme_light .content {
   background: #theme-light-background-color;
   color: #theme-light-font-color;
}

.theme_light .button {
   background: #theme-light-button-background-color;
   color: #theme-light-button-font-color;
} 


/* stylings dark theme */

.theme_dark .content {
   background: #theme-dark-background-color;
   color: #theme-dark-font-color;
}

.theme_dark .button {
   background: #theme-dark-button-background-color;
   color: #theme-dark-button-font-color;
} 
  

// if you anchor with app class your css-selectors would have to be

/* light theme */
.app_root.theme_light .content { ... }
.app_root.theme_light .content { ... }

/* dark theme */
.app_root.theme_dark .content { ... }
.app_root.theme_dark .content { ... }
```

#### 3. Use your SASS-function/-map to achieve this in `SASS`

In this step we use your (still working) function and map from your question. Writing the CSS in SASS is as easy with nesting the element classes ...

```
// write themes dark & white nested to the anchor classes
// use function & map from question

.theme_light {

   // set sass theme varible 
   // to get from function values for theme light
   $theme: light;


   // write stylings
   // function will automatic return values for light theme
   body {
      background: semantic-color('background', 'base');
      color: semantic-color('text-color', 'base'); 
   }
   button {
      background: semantic-color('buttons', 'primary');
      color: semantic-color('buttons-text', 'primary'); 
   }

}


.theme_dark {

   // set sass theme varible 
   // to get from function values for theme dark
   $theme: dark;


   // write stylings
   // function will automatic NOW return values for light theme
   body {
      background: semantic-color('background', 'base');
      color: semantic-color('text-color', 'base'); 
   }
   button {
      background: semantic-color('buttons', 'primary');
      color: semantic-color('buttons-text', 'primary'); 
   }

}

//### 
//### --> that will compile the needed css!!!
//###


//### NOTE:
//--> if you use app-anchor-class 
//--> your nesting would be as follow

.app_root.theme_light { ... same code as above ... } 
.app_root.theme_dark { ... same code as above ... }
```

#### HINTS:

1. As you see your function is a powerful tool: as shown in the example it leads to write identical code twice. If you write a SASS mixin (use directive `@content` to pass individual theme styles to it) you can reduce it so you are able to write all themes at once.
2. As you see the SASS variable `$theme` is used IN SASS as switch which changes your function `semantic-color()` to get the right color (light or dark).
3. There are many approches to realize theme stylings in SASS. This is one of the traditional methods and having a good organized map a very intuitive one.